# In Star Wars IV, could Darth Vader have captured Obi-Wan Kenobi's lightsaber using Force Pull?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, a-new-hope, darth-vader

In Star Wars IV: A New Hope, when Obi-Wan Kenobi finds Darth Vader on the Death Star, he takes out his lightsaber and turns it on. At this point, could Vader have captured Kenobi's lightsaber using Force Pull since his Force powers were stronger than Obi-Wan's Force powers?

Vader points this out during their lightsaber duel when he tells Kenobi "...your powers are weak old man...".

Comment: Sure... that "could" have happened... but if it was in the script Obi-Wan could have shown his true power after Vader said that, killed everybody all by himself, and gotten the rebels a new Death Star setting them up nicely for the sequel... alas, the script was the script...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yoda does precisely that to Asajj Ventress in episode two of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, [“Ambush”](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ambush). He turns off her lightsaber(s), pulls them out of her hands and then smack-talks her for a few seconds before handing them back.

We can reasonably assume that while Vader feels that Obi-Wan has become weak and old, he's not yet in a position where he can simply disarm him with the Force (or else he would have done so immediately).

Comment: It's worth checking out the auto subtitles on this video. **AV:** *I don't fear you, Jedi*. **YD:** *Strong you are with the dark side, young one, but not that strong*. ***woosh. vrp vrp.*** **YD:** *Still much to learn, you have.* ***woosh.*** **YD:** *Surrender, you should*. ***Explosion. Crumbling. Vyyrrrrrrr***.

Comment: Of course Ventress doesn't have nearly the skills that old Obi Wan has. All those telekinetic tricks don't seem to be something that anyone tries on fully credentialed Jedi.